# how to highlight nav tab state1 when we are in state3

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I have a situation where I need to highlight nav tab `state1` when we are in `state3` using `ui-router` concept. `State3` is inside the `state1` html.

Below is my code:

```
<nav> 
    <a ui-sref="state1" ui-sref-active="active">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2" ui-sref-active="active">State 2</a>
</nav>

<div ui-view></div>

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("state1", {
        url: "#",
        template: "<p>State 1 <a ui-sref='state3'>details</a></p>",
      })
      .state("state2", {
        url: "#",
        template: "<p>State 2</p>",
      })
      .state('state3', {
            url: "#",
            template: "<h2>state1 details</h2>",
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/789Ks/168/)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know ui-sref-active concept .But By using jquery you can do it. http://jsfiddle.net/akhilap/2cbtLtdt/3/

Comment: @AkhilaPrakash it is good, but i am looking for angularjs solution

Comment: I will try to help you .

Answer (score 0):

Look at this alternative of your code. I've added the link to version 0.2.15 of angular-router and the usage of one more ui-view control for the child view. Does it suit?

```
<nav> 
    <a ui-sref="state1" ui-sref-active="active">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2" ui-sref-active="active">State 2</a>
</nav>

<div ui-view></div>

var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router", "AppCtrls"]);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("state1", {
        url: "/state1",
        template: "<p>State 1 <a ui-sref='.state3'>details</a><ui-view /></p>",
      })
      .state("state2", {
        url: "/state2",
        template: "<p>State 2</p>",
      })
      .state('state1.state3', {
            url: "/state3",
            template: "<h2>state1 details</h2>",
        });
});

var ctrls = angular.module("AppCtrls", []);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jahn08/f1owscs5/

Comment: thanks for your time, but here I can not use nested views